# KDE 5 installs without task bar on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma

I just installed a fresh Arch Linux. After successfully starting the system, I only had a text console, but want to have a KDE desktop as I had on my Debian installation. So I followed the steps at [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plasma) and installed KDE 5 Plasma with SDDM as the display manager. I started it with

```
systemctl start sddm
```

and I could login successfull. After the login, I got an desktop with 3 tags at the left hand side, Pictures, Music and Videos. But there was no task bar! I tried to add a taskbar by right-clicking on the desktop, but no popup menu opened like it was back in KDE 4.

Here is a screenshot (made by my phone since I have no idea how to do that on the new system):
[image]

How can I get a task bar in KDE 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to choose "Plasma" instead of "Plasma Media Center" (which is default) session in the sddm. I just got caught too =)